# Windows 7 RC x86 debug symbols for user32.dll

Tags: windows-7

The Windows 7 RC x86 symbol pack doesn't seem to include symbols for `user32.dll` or `KernelBase.dll`.  I've tried downloading the symbols from the microsoft symbol server (using [symchk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc267474.aspx)) with no luck.

Has anyone been able to get debugging symbols for `user32.dll` or `KernelBase.dll` for the Windows 7 release candidate?  I really miss having a complete call stack in the debugger.

Comment: the RC is still WIP - maybe it's intentional...

Comment: It looks like the x64 symbols include user32 and kernelbase.

Comment: Yeah, seems like they screwed up the release a bit.  I haven't been able to find them either.